# Xcode Substitutions

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have created an application that works on Mac Os X that displays an HTML5 program in JQuery Mobile that I programmed using Fluid. I would like to program another version of this application that works on iPhone and, if possible, other iOS devices. I am trying to download Xcode, but the file is so large that my browser first says that it is going to take 14 days, then it just says "Cancled." And yes, I have tryed it with a stronger WiFi conection, the same thing happened. I heard that Apple start-up discs have Xcode on them, but I can't find any of them. Is there a substitution for Xcode that you can use to program iOS devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no substitute.  Have you tried downloading it via the App Store?

Comment: Yes, it just said "failed."